# Overbrace on a line

Tags: overbrace

I wanna make this in Overleaf. I've see many diagrams like this in 3b1b's video.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What do you mean with "3b1b's video"? Please explain your issue better, for example what have you tried?

Comment: (Just a comment: The style of the picture looks like the one in Needham's books. I think he uses some external tool.)

Comment: @Mensch yeah Sir I'm talking about famous math channel "3Blue1Brown". He uses his own mathematical software Manim but Manim also uses latex. That's why I asked.

Comment: @mickep Sir what is Needham's book I searched but got many books in result. I took this Image from the book called "Visual Complex Analysis".

Comment: @Mensch Yeah and I tried like this using Tikz package :\overbrace{\draw (0,0) -- (3,3)} 
 but didn't work :(

Comment: And who wrote that book? :D

Comment: @mickep "Tristan Needham" 0hh haha I just realized . Sorry for late reply I was just doing some work and now i opened website in my laptop. But really I didn't noticed author's name.

Answer (score 3):

A line can be braced in `TikZ` using `decorations.pathreplacing`. If the nodes are `O` and `AB` then the commands

```
\draw[very thick, -stealth](O)--(AB);
\draw[decorate, decoration={brace}](O.center)--(AB.center);
```

will draw the line (with stealth arrow) and then draw the brace. The brace can be shifted away from the nodes with `raise=` and the "height" of the brace can be controlled with `amplitude=`. You can then add a label to the brace by placing a `node` with the desired label using the `sloped` option (and shifting with `yshift=`) as in the code below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw, circle, inner sep=1pt, label={180:0}] at (0,0)(O){};
\node[fill, circle, inner sep=1pt, label={0:$AB$}] at (1,4)(AB){};
\node[fill, circle, inner sep=1pt, label={0:$B$}] at (1,2)(B){};
\node[fill, circle, inner sep=1pt, label={0:$A$}] at (4,1)(A){};
\draw[very thick, -stealth](O)--(AB);
\draw[decorate, decoration={brace, raise=3pt, amplitude=6pt}](O.center)--
    node[sloped, yshift=15pt]{$(\mathrm{length}\,A)\cdot(\mathrm{length}\,B)$}(AB.center);
\draw[very thick, -stealth](O)--(B);
\draw[very thick, -stealth](O)--(A);
\draw[thick, dotted](O)--(4,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The marked angles can be added using the `angles` library. The arrow tips in your example look like `Triangle` style, which requires `arrows.meta`, and the `bending` library will get the heads pointed in the right direction. Add the following code:

```
\usetikzlibrary {decorations.pathreplacing, angles, arrows.meta, bending} % in preamble

\draw pic [draw, angle radius=1.2cm, -Triangle] {angle=X--O--B};
\draw pic [draw, angle radius=1.2cm, -Triangle] {angle=X--O--AB};
\draw pic [draw, angle radius=1cm, -Triangle] {angle=X--O--A};
\draw pic [draw, angle radius=1cm, -Triangle] {angle=X--O--AB};
```

[image]

Comment: It would be better if the angle arrow heads were the same as the edge arrow heads.

Comment: @M.Logic: That is not what appears in the image that OP provided.

Comment: @SandyG Thank you very much sir !! Now it is clear.  would you like to tell me "From where can I learn this types of packages ?" ?

Comment: But a good improvement, and the bracket in your post is also improved. By the way, the line thickness of A, B and AB shouldn't be so large to a high aesthetical standard.

Comment: @Luckychouhan: You're welcome. The [TikZ/PGF manual](https://pgf-tikz.github.io/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) is a good place to learn. Don't worry that it's so long. The first few chapters are nicely written tutorials. I recommend focussing on section I, chapters 1–5. Also, please remember the [Code of Conduct](https://tex.stackexchange.com/conduct) instructs us to use gender-neutral language. Don't call users "sir". Some of the people helping you are women.

Comment: @SandyG Thank you very much! I'm surely gonna see that manual.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done with `pstricks-add`, using a relatively short code:

```
    \documentclass[border=12pt, svgnames]{standalone}%
    \usepackage{pstricks-add, pst-eucl}

    \begin{document}

    \psset{arrowinset=0.12, linejoin=1, unit=2cm, braceWidth=0.4pt}
    \begin{pspicture}(-0.5,-0.5)(2.5,2)
    \pstGeonode(2; 20){A}(1; 50){B}(2; 70){AB}
    \pstGeonode[PointSymbol=o, PosAngle=180](0,0){O}
    \pnode(2.2,0){X}\ncline[linestyle=dotted, dotsep=2pt, nodesepA=2pt]{O}{X}
    \psset{arrows=->, nodesepA=2pt, nodesepB=3pt}\ncline{O}{A}\ncline{O}{B}\ncline{O}{AB}
    \psbrace[rot=70, nodesep=-1pt](AB)(O){\makebox[0pt]{(length A)$\cdot$(length B)}}
     \end{pspicture}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much sir !! May I know " from where can I learn this new packages ?" ?

Comment: @Luckychouhan:  well, you have the pstricks web site `https://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi/`, and the documentation of the pstricks  packages, which has manyy examples.